# Two matching selects' values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two selects mirroring the same composite value - changing one should change the other:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="type" class="control-label col-sm-2">First:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
              <select name="general[first]" id="first" class="chosen-select-no-single"
                      data-placeholder="Choose first"
                      chosen="dataArray"
                      ng-options="row as row.first for row in dataArray"
                      ng-model="selectedItem"
                      ng-check="selectedItem"
                      style="width: 100%;">
               </select>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="type" class="control-label col-sm-2">Second:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
              <select name="general[second]" id="second" class="chosen-select-no-single"
                      data-placeholder="Choose second"
                      chosen="dataArray"
                      ng-options="row as row.second for row in dataArray"
                            ng-model="selectedItem"
                            ng-change="update()"
                            ng-check="selectedItem"
                            style="width: 100%;">
               </select>
          </div>
</div>
```

It works, but the values are not correct. I want the values to be `row.first` and `row.second`, whereas right now it's `object:8`, or `object:6`.

I tried setting `ng-options` to `row.first as row.first`, but this way the selects don't match - changing the first doesn't change the second.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `track by`, like this:

```
ng-options="row as row.second for row in dataArray track by row.second"
```

This way I can achieve both, value matching in multiple selects and values as I want them.